# Run a upload in background with base64 file

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I work with radiology medical reports. Doctors record the report in a audio file and close the browser after this, so the browser doesn't have time to upload the file. I tried to put a loading with a warning about the time to upload and the need to stay with browser open, but they don't respect it and the accuracy of loading screen is not very correct.

My question is: since I have a audio file encoded in base64, there is a way to run this upload in background or keep this to upload in another screen request?
My point is, there is a way to upload the files without any dependency of the user?

If it helps, I`m using CodeIgniter.

Thanks

Comment: If possible, can describe the process which _stops_ the recording when doctor completes audio report ? button press ?, other dialog prompt ? Thanks

Comment: Today we use WAMI Flash plugin to record, but i'm changing to html5, when the user stops the record, audio file is sent to a controller that look for a previous audio in that report and append then, if exists. Otherwise this will send to a folder in server. The action to stop and start recording is a button press. Tks for the answer.

Comment: Could possibly add an `event` listener to the button `click` event , clone the data (audio / base64 string), do other stuff ; i.e.g, `POST` (upload) the data to server ?

Comment: It exactly what it does, but there is no enough time to upload this data to server to work out and save the audio file. That's why I need another form to save without any dependency of user.

Comment: Not certain how the file could be saved if not enough time to save file ? Another approach could save the audio _during_ the actual recording , as chunks of data (blobs) , then on button click append all of the chucks to a single blob (file).

Comment: There is no time to upload the audio file to server and the doctors do not wait until finish the upload. How can be made a record and upload simultaneously?

Comment: Not certain about `WAMI Flash` , though if audio (data) is being recorded , could , perhaps simultaneously `append` chunks of the recorded data to a `blob`. When user stops recording session , all recorded data should be available as a single blob (file) . At moment of button click to complete recording , should have all recordings in single blob - and utilize same button click to upload file. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File ,https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_Storage_API

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm looking for this side... I'm thinking about localStorage and some control that delete the file if it was not upload to the server. I'm trying to follow this example http://www.ellipsetours.com/Demos/storage/ making the adjustments for my case. Do you think its possible to control with the files in localStorage and some flag?

Comment: Not certain ? Should be possible , though ; with either https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset .  Though the `File` or `Blob` interface may also provide adequate methods to adjust or delete the data.